# IMO 1966 Shortlist Inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Prove that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\sin\alpha})+\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\cos x}{\cos\alpha})>1$ where $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{6}<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Now I shaw that if $u=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\sin\alpha}$ and $v=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\cos x}{\cos\alpha}$ then $(1)$ $u,v\in [0,\pi/2)$ ; $(2)$ $u+v>\frac{\pi}{4}$. I ask how to complete that $\tan u+\tan v>1$

Comment: At least either $\tan u>1$ or $\tan v>1$ always holds. So...

Comment: how did you see it?

Comment: $\sin x>\sin \alpha,\cos x>\cos\alpha$.

Comment: Ohh I saw why. Suppose both $u,v<\frac{\pi}{4}$. Then $u=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\sin x}{\sin\alpha}<\frac{\pi}{4} ; \frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\cos x}{\cos\alpha}<\frac{\pi}{4}$ Hence $0<\sin x<\sin\alpha , 0<\cos x<\cos\alpha$ take square and add then $1<1$ contradiction... Thus at least one of $u,v$ is greater than $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: And $u$ or $v >0$ from $\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha  >\frac12$.

Comment: not "or" both $u,v\geq 0$ it is clear

Answer (score 0):

First:when $ u+v < \frac{\pi}{2} $

[1] $  \frac{\tan u + \tan v }{1 - \tan u \cdot \tan v  } = \tan(u+v) > 1 $

and we know

[2]: $ \tan u \geq 0$ and $ \tan v \geq 0 $

so  $1   > \tan u \cdot \tan v  $ beacuse [1]

[1'] : $ \tan u + \tan v > 1 - \tan u \cdot \tan v $

but by [2],  $ \tan u \cdot \tan v  \geq 0$

finally,  we get

$ \tan u + \tan v > 1 $

Second:  $ \frac{\pi}{2} < u+v < 1$

Let $\frac{\pi}{4} - w = u$ .then we get $ v > \frac{\pi}{4} + w$

but $ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \tan x}{\mathrm{d} x^2} >0 $  so

$ 1 \leq \tan ( \frac{u+v}{2}) \leq \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\tan u + \tan v)$

finally,  we get

$ \tan u + \tan v > 2 $

Comment: Are you sure? @G.H.Lee?

Comment: I have fixed some error in my proof.

Comment: you say $\tan u \tan v\geq 0$ but then $1-\tan u\tan v>1$?? in the first part again something wrong... @G.H.Lee

Comment: Umm...You're right... . I'm sorry.  and    I'll fix my answer.